# Best way to deploy git projects (with submodules) to FTP server

Tags: git, deployment, git-submodules

Hey guys. There is capistrano but that only works for ssh servers, which a lot of our clients aren't. We also make use of git submodules extensively. What is the best way you know of deploying git projects (with submodules) to FTP servers?

I've tried Beanstalk and Springloops v2 but they are both falling quite short. Beanstalk often fails, and springloops v2 is still struggling intensely.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use DeployHQ. http://deployhq.com
They link nicely with CodebaseHQ, their SVN, Git and Hg repository hosting service.
You can deploy to an SSH, SFTP or FTP server. I use it on a number of projects I am currently working on.

Comment: Worked out well, used it for a few months. Now I use MediaTemple as my host and they support git on their SSH access, so I just do git clones and pulls now for deployment :D